# How to create More then one table in magento?

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, database, table, install-script

How to create More then one table in magento with installer script ?

Comment: Just like you create one table create the other. See an example of how multiple tables are created in the same install script in `app/code/core/Mage/Cms/sql/cms_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below code is use for creating multiple tables in installer scrips.

```
<?php 

$installer = $this; 

$installer->startSetup(); 

$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('module_learning/basedata'))
    ->addColumn('ticket_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Id')
    ->addColumn('title', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Title')
    ->addColumn('description', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Description');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('module_learning/comment'))
    ->addColumn('comment_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Id')
    ->addColumn('comment', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Comment');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: is there any change in config.xml

Comment: you have to change your table name and fields name only.

Comment: can you explain in brief ?

Comment: Yes, you need to define model & resource node in config.xml file inside global tag. Your multiple table name pass on inside entities tag

Comment: <entities><page><table>cms_page</table></page><page_store><table>cms_page_store</table></page_store></entities>

Comment: perfect answer!!! +1 :)